# Java reflection: Is the constructor parameter order guaranteed

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, annotation-processing

I created my own annotation to annotate constructors:

```
@MyConstructorAnnotation
public Constructor(int param1, int param2) {
    this.param1 = param1;
    this.param2 = param2;
}
```

I wrote an annotation processor which reads the parameter names of each annotated constructor. This is inside the *process()* method:

```
for (Element element : annotatedElements)) {
    Field paramsField = element.getClass().getField("params");
    Iterable parameters = (Iterable) paramsField.get(element);
        for (Object parameter : parameters) {
            String name = parameter.toString();
            // do something with the name
        }
}
```

This may not be very clean, but it gets me the names "param1" and "param2". I tested that with 10+ parameters and the order was still correct. My question is: Is it **guaranteed** that the parameters will be in the correct order?

Comment: Wouldn't be much use otherwise.

Comment: @user207421 Yeah. But the order of fields/methods is not guaranteed when using reflection, which is a bit weird aswell.

Comment: No, it’s not weird. The declaration order of fields and methods has no meaning to the Java program. In contrast, swapping the arguments for a method or constructor call would change the meaning of the program.